# 2D morton code encode/decode 64bits

Tags: c, 64-bit, z-order-curve

How to encode/decode morton codes(z-order) given [x, y] as 32bit unsigned integers producing 64bit morton code, and vice verse ?
I do have xy2d and d2xy but only for coordinates that are 16bits wide producing 32bit morton number. Searched a lot in net, but couldn't find. Please help.

Comment: It's really not hard to extend a 32bit version to 64bit. Double the width of all the masks, and add an extra step following the same pattern as the others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it is possible for you to use architecture specific instructions you'll likely be able to accelerate the operation beyond what is possible using bit-twiddeling hacks:

For example if you write code for the Intel Haswell and later CPUs you can use the BMI2 instruction set which contains the `pext` and `pdep` instructions. These can (among other great things) be used to build your functions.

Here is a complete example (tested with GCC):

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// on GCC, compile with option -mbmi2, requires Haswell or better.

uint64_t xy_to_morton(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
  return _pdep_u32(x, 0x55555555) | _pdep_u32(y,0xaaaaaaaa);
}

void morton_to_xy(uint64_t m, uint32_t *x, uint32_t *y)
{
  *x = _pext_u64(m, 0x5555555555555555);
  *y = _pext_u64(m, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa);
}
```

If you have to support earlier CPUs or the ARM platform not all is lost. You may still get at least get help for the xy_to_morton function from instructions specific for cryptography.

A lot of CPUs have support for carry-less multiplication these days. On ARM that'll be `vmul_p8` from the NEON instruction set. On X86 you'll find it as `PCLMULQDQ` from the CLMUL instruction set (available since 2010).

The trick here is, that a carry-less multiplication of a number with itself will return a bit-pattern that contains the original bits of the argument with zero-bits interleaved. So it is identical to the _pdep_u32(x,0x55555555) shown above. E.g. it turns the following byte:

```
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 | b7 | b6 | b5 | b4 | b3 | b2 | b1 | b0 |
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Into:

```
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 | 0  | b7 | 0  | b6 | 0  | b5 | 0  | b4 | 0  | b3 | 0  | b2 | 0  | b1 | 0  | b0 |
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now you can build the xy_to_morton function as (here shown for CLMUL instruction set):

```
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// on GCC, compile with option -mpclmul

uint64_t carryless_square (uint32_t x)
{
  uint64_t val[2] = {x, 0};
  __m128i *a = (__m128i * )val;
  *a = _mm_clmulepi64_si128 (*a,*a,0);
  return val[0];
}

uint64_t xy_to_morton (uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
  return carryless_square(x)|(carryless_square(y) <<1);
}
```

`_mm_clmulepi64_si128` generates a 128 bit result of which we only use the lower 64 bits. So you can even improve upon the version above and use a single _mm_clmulepi64_si128 do do the job.

That is as good as you can get on mainstream platforms (e.g. modern ARM with NEON and x86). Unfortunately I don't know of any trick to speed up the morton_to_xy function using the cryptography instructions and I tried really hard for several month.

Comment: Really great. Appritiate.

Comment: @DawidSzymański If you want more I suggest you check out this blog: bitmath.blogspot.de and read about tesseral arithmetic (that's doing arithmetic with numbers stored in morton order without encoding/decoding them). I'm pretty sure you can use it for your space-filling curve stuff.

Comment: @harold, fun fact is: We have enjoy the mathematical odditiy of the bit-twiddeling powers of the x*x operation in GF(2'm). However, the crypto-folks like to have a fast sqrt(x) in GF(2'm) as well. They already found out about that it is about separating even from odd bits, but they don't know the bit-twiddling hacks yet.. I think everyone can learn from that!

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck hitting this answer after so long, inquisitive for the fact  whether they exist for a 3D space ? say encoding x,y,z to Z order and vice versa.

Answer (score 11):

```
void xy2d_morton(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t *d)
{
    x = (x | (x << 16)) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
    x = (x | (x << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
    x = (x | (x << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
    x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
    x = (x | (x << 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;

    y = (y | (y << 16)) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
    y = (y | (y << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
    y = (y | (y << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
    y = (y | (y << 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
    y = (y | (y << 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;

    *d = x | (y << 1);
}

// morton_1 - extract even bits

uint32_t morton_1(uint64_t x)
{
    x = x & 0x5555555555555555;
    x = (x | (x >> 1))  & 0x3333333333333333;
    x = (x | (x >> 2))  & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
    x = (x | (x >> 4))  & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
    x = (x | (x >> 8))  & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
    x = (x | (x >> 16)) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    return (uint32_t)x;
}

void d2xy_morton(uint64_t d, uint64_t &x, uint64_t &y)
{
    x = morton_1(d);
    y = morton_1(d >> 1);
}
```

Comment: In `morton_1`, shouldn't that last value be `0x00000000FFFFFFFF`?

Comment: p.s. `morton_1` could return a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 5):

The naïve code would be the same irregardless of the bit count. If you don't need super fast bit twiddling version, this will do

```
uint32_t x;
uint32_t y;
uint64_t z = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * 8; i++)
{
  z |= (x & (uint64_t)1 << i) << i | (y & (uint64_t)1 << i) << (i + 1);
}
```

If you need faster bit twiddling, then this one should work. Note that x and y have to be 64bit variables.

```
uint64_t x;
uint64_t y;
uint64_t z = 0;

x = (x | (x << 16)) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
x = (x | (x << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
x = (x | (x << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
x = (x | (x << 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;

y = (y | (y << 16)) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
y = (y | (y << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
y = (y | (y << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
y = (y | (y << 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
y = (y | (y << 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;

z = x | (y << 1);
```

Comment: More interested in fast way, and reverse ?