# How to combine 2 4-bit unsigned numbers into 1 8-bit number in C

Tags: c, concatenation

I have 2 4-bit numbers (X0X1X2X3 and Y0Y1Y2Y3) and I want to combine them so that I would create an 8-bit number like that:

```
X0X1X2X3 
Y0Y1Y2Y3  => X0Y0X1Y1X2Y2X3Y3
```

I know how to concatenate them in order to create the `X0X1X1X3Y0Y1Y2Y3` but I am stuck on how to compose them in the pattern explained above.

Any hints?

Comment: How about a loop taking one bit each from the two 4-bit numbers each iteration?

Comment: Look at bitshifting and logical or operations

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539347/2d-morton-code-encode-decode-64bits

Comment: Start_Number = (Start_Number_High << 4) | (Start_Number_Low & 0xF);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly direct way of performing this transformation:

```
uint8_t result;
result |= (x & 8) << 4;
result |= (y & 8) << 3;
result |= (x & 4) << 3;
result |= (y & 4) << 2;
result |= (x & 2) << 2;
result |= (y & 2) << 1;
result |= (x & 1) << 1;
result |= (y & 1) << 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

A very quick way of interleaving four-bit numbers is with a look-up table:

```
unsigned int spread[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x05, 0x10, 0x11, 0x14, 0x15, 
    0x40, 0x41, 0x44, 0x45, 0x50, 0x51, 0x54, 0x55
};
```

You can use `spread[]` array, which "spreads" bits of the original, to construct your output as follows:

```
unsigned int res = (spread[x] << 1) | spread[y];
```

The trick is in the construction of the look-up table. Its values are selected in such a way that the bits of the index are interleaved with zeros. For example, `0x07`, or 0111<sub>2</sub>, becomes `0x15`, or 00010101<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Of course, this is feasible only if the number is small.  If you have too many bits this `spread` array may be too big to be worthwhile.

Comment: @NathanFellman A table with 256 entries would be sufficient to deal with most numbers one byte at a time, rather than one bit at a time. Since OP specifically asks for four-bit numbers, it shouldn't be an issue for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in one line.

```
 uint8_t result =  (varX << 4) | (varY);
```