# How could I 0-interleave a number (binary)?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

If I have `11`, I'd like to perform some kind of bitwise operation and get `1010`.

If I have `111`, `101010`.

If I have `101`, `100010`.

Can I do this? How?

If so, is it possible to do this arbitrarily, i.e., if I wanted to interleave 8 0-bits for 8 value-bits:
`11101110 01101010` -> `11101110 00000000 01101010 00000000`

Comment: I recognize this may be better for CSE. Let me know if I should migrate.

Comment: It's not a true duplicate but you can use the same techniques as [Morton encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30539347/555045) (but with only half the code)

Comment: Thanks! Trying to internalize Morton encoding. While I do, would you know if it is possible to interleave an arbitrary number of 0-bits between an arbitrary number of valued bits using Morton encoding?

Comment: Yes, but some of the approaches easily allow that and some of them don't. There are also versions that interleave 3 coordinates (and can therefore be used to insert 2 zero bits between every bit) and 4 and so on. The version based on `pdep` is extremely flexible in how many zeroes it inserts and where, but limited to certain hardware.